# Troubleshooting MongoDB Atlas Database Integration with Custom Chatbot: YAML POST Action Failing

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm working on integrating a MongoDB Atlas database with a custom chatbot I've developed. I've set up an action in YAML format, designed to make a POST request to retrieve data from the database. This involves using an API key for authentication. However, while this action works correctly when I test it through the terminal, it fails when I try it within my chatbot system (I've attached a screenshot of the failure).

Below is my YAML schema for this action. Please note that I have already verified the names of the database, collection, and cluster, and have confirmed that the YAML syntax is correct. The schema is as follows:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: MongoDB Atlas API
  version: "1.0"
servers:
  - url: 'https://eu-central-1.aws.data.mongodb-api.com'
paths:
  /app/data-atqsq/endpoint/data/v1/action/find:
    post:
      summary: Retrieve documents from a MongoDB collection
      operationId: findDocuments
      tags:
        - documents
      parameters:
        - in: header
          name: X-Api-Key
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
          description: Your MongoDB Atlas API key
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                collection:
                  type: string
                  example: #'my collection name'
                database:
                  type: string
                  example: #'my db name'
                dataSource:
                  type: string
                  example: #'my ds name'
      responses:
        '200':
           description: A list of documents.
           content:
             application/json:
               schema:
                 type: array
                 items:
                   type: object
        '400':
           description: Bad Request.
        '404':
          description: The specified cluster, database, or collection could not be found.
```

Can anyone offer guidance or assistance on why the action is failing in the chatbot system but works in the terminal?